# With XSLT, how can I use this if-test with an array, when search element is returned by a template call inside the for loop?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, for-loop, xsl-choose

I think this simple example might ask the question a lot more clearly.

I have an input file with multiple products.  There are  different types of product (2 types with 2 product IDs is fine enough for this example), but the input will have many more.

I only want to output the info for the first product of each type that I encounter in the for each Product loop.  (I'm outputting info for the lowest priced product, so the first one will be the lowest price because I sort by Rate first.)

So I want to read in each product, but only output the product's info if I haven't already output a product with that same ID.  I have a variable for the IDArray, and I want to check if each product inside the for each product loop has an ID that is already in that IDArray - if not, continue, if it is already in the array, skip everything and just loop to the next.

I couldn't figure out how to get the child element to be a node from IDArray with the value of each CurrentID.  It keeps adding that value as a node to CurrentID which is only in the scope of each product, not the whole product group.  I know the following code does not work, but it illustrates the idea and gives me a place to start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="prod_name adv_notes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <List>
     <xsl:for-each select="ProductGroup">
     <xsl:sort select="Product/Rate"/>
     <xsl:variable name="IDarray">
     <xsl:for-each select="Product">
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentID">
           <xsl:call-template name="processID">
              <xsl:with-param name="ProductCode" select="ProductCode" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($IDarray, $CurrentID))">
           <child elem="{@elem}">
             <xsl:select value-of="$CurrentID" />
           </child>
          <Product>
           <xsl:attribute name="ID">
             <xsl:select value-of="$CurrentID" />
           </xsl:attribute>
        <prod_name>
           <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/>
        </prod_name>
        <rate>
           <xsl:value-of select="Rate"/>
        </rate>
    </Product>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </List>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="processID">
 <xsl:param name="ProductCode"/>
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="starts-with($ProductCode, '515')">5</xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="starts-with($ProductCode, '205')">2</xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks so much in advance, I know some of the awesome programmers here can help! :)
-Holly

An input would look like this:

```
 <ProductGroup>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>
       5155
    </ProductCode>
    <ProductName>
       House
    </ProductName>
    <Rate>
       3.99
    </Rate>
    </Product>
    <Product>
    <ProductCode>
       5158
    </ProductCode>
    <ProductName>
       House
    </ProductName>
    <Rate>
       4.99
    </Rate>
    </Product>
   </ProductGroup>
        <ProductGroup>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>
       2058
    </ProductCode>
    <ProductName>
       House
    </ProductName>
    <Rate>
       2.99
    </Rate>
    </Product>
    <Product>
    <ProductCode>
       2055
    </ProductCode>
    <ProductName>
       House
    </ProductName>
    <Rate>
       7.99
    </Rate>
    </Product>
   </ProductGroup>
```

Output would be this for only that simple input file:

[image]

Implementing a Muenchian grouping is tough here because my actual dataset is huge.  I made it simple to ask a question.  If I can just get that array method working, the rest of my huge project will work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A small example of XML input and this would be a very good first question.

Comment: Also, please, provide the exact wanted output from the transformation.

Comment: You need to read about *grouping*. For XSLT 1.0 the most efficient grouping method is the *Muenchian grouping* : http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html . For XSLT 2.0 one uses the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction -- read about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping

Comment: Added a small input/output.  Sorry about that!!

Answer (score 2):

> how can I use this if-test with an array, when search element is
>   returned by a template call inside the for loop?

**UPDATE**: You're using XSLT 1.0 so your only option to create an array is to use extensions and that might or might not be possible depending on your environment (see  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040841/handling-array-like-variable-with-xslt/) for more information). My guess this would be complicated and not very efficient in comparison with keys anyway.

A better question is

> I have an input file with multiple products. There are 10 types of
>   product (10 product IDs), but the input will have 200 products, and I
>   only want to output the info for the first product of each type.

The following is an example of how to achieve that. I'd rather use your input and desired output but unfortunately they were not provided.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductGroup>
  <Product ID="Product 1" Type="A"/>
  <Product ID="Product 2" Type="B"/>
  <Product ID="Product 3" Type="C"/>
  <Product ID="Product 4" Type="A"/>
  <Product ID="Product 5" Type="B"/>
  <Product ID="Product 6" Type="C"/>
  <Product ID="Product 7" Type="A"/>
  <Product ID="Product 8" Type="B"/>
  <Product ID="Product 9" Type="C"/>
</ProductGroup>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="Product-by-Type" match="Product" use="@Type" />
  <xsl:template match="/ProductGroup">
    <Products>
      <xsl:for-each select="Product[count(. | key('Product-by-Type', @Type)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="@Type" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('Product-by-Type', @Type)[1]" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Products>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product ID="Product 1" Type="A" />
  <Product ID="Product 2" Type="B" />
  <Product ID="Product 3" Type="C" />
</Products>
```

[This post](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) provides a very good explanation of how Muenchian grouping works.

**UPDATE**

Your help with more information is really appreciated. Here's how I'd get from your input to your output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="Product-by-ProductCode" match="Product" use="concat(normalize-space(../../preceding-sibling::Purpose[1]), substring(normalize-space(ProductCode), 1, 3))" />
  <xsl:template match="/List">
    <List>
      <xsl:for-each select="ProductGroup/ActiveProducts/Product[count(. | key('Product-by-ProductCode', concat(normalize-space(../../preceding-sibling::Purpose[1]), substring(normalize-space(ProductCode), 1, 3)))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="Rate" />
        <xsl:element name="Product">
          <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="concat(normalize-space(../../preceding-sibling::Purpose[1]), substring(normalize-space(ProductCode), 1, 3)) = 'Purchase515'">5</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="concat(normalize-space(../../preceding-sibling::Purpose[1]), substring(normalize-space(ProductCode), 1, 3)) = 'Rent205'">2</xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:element name="prod_name">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('Product-by-ProductCode', concat(normalize-space(../../preceding-sibling::Purpose[1]), substring(normalize-space(ProductCode), 1, 3)))[1]/ProductName"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="rate">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('Product-by-ProductCode', concat(normalize-space(../../preceding-sibling::Purpose[1]), substring(normalize-space(ProductCode), 1, 3)))[1]/Rate"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </List>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The approach is the same as in my earlier example, except the key is a concatenation of `Purpose` and `ProductCode`. There might be an issue with your input, I thing `<Purpose>Rent</Purpose>` is missing before the second product group.

Comment: @codesforcoffee Could you please edit your question to include all the details?

Comment: @codesforcoffee No worries. While we're at it, perhaps you could add the output you want too?

Comment: @Serge Belov  Sure!   Since I'm re-creating a more simple version of my super huge set of data, I am trying not to make typos... my solution actually worked until they asked me to only output one of each, not all of them.  So I am trying to add the if and array of IDs properly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @codesforcoffee I guess I've provided the best answer I could; my personal opinion (please feel free to ignore it) is that variables and loops are really easy to (mis)use in a way that violates the spirit of XSLT. A functional template-based alternative is usually shorter and more efficient. Good luck with the issue!

Comment: I saw your update, but I'm not understanding how you get the ID without calling the template processID to derive it from the product code... hmm.

Comment: @codesforcoffee My bad, I used `ID` instead of `ProcessId`, give me a couple of minutes to correct it.

Comment: Since my data is actually a lot more complicated, I'd really like to try and implement the array and just check with each Product if the ID was already put into that array, and if not, then add it and continue.  Does anyone know how I can do that?  Right now, it keeps adding the $CurrentID as a node to itself, instead of a node to the more global array variable that will keep its elements for the next loop.

Comment: @codesforcoffee You might have missed my update in the top part of the answer: you're using XSLT 1.0 so your only option to create an array is to use extensions and that might or might not be possible depending on your environment (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040841/handling-array-like-variable-with-xslt/) for more information). `node-set` should get you there.

Comment: I'm not sure what "node-set" should get you there means though, shall I try something like xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($IDarray)/node($CurrentID)" or how does that work?

Comment: @codesforcoffee Before I go answering that, could you please update your question with the following info: (1) why exactly are you insisting on doing this using an array rather than a more traditional approach? (2) What exactly is so complicated about your data that you haven't mentioned yet? (3) Have you tried `node-set` as described in the post I referred you to and if so what exactly didn't work? Thanks.

Comment: My problem is a whole lot more complicated, so I tried to make a simple example that I could ask a question with.

The reality is that I'm translating it for another company that has their own IDs I have to assign based on 3 or 4 parameters.

I really needed to figure out the way where I'd add each product ID that I assign to an array so the next time I come across that type, I just skip that loop because that type of product was already done. 

Any idea how to make that node-set method work? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I never got it to work, so I added a class to my software to do all of this instead.  Then I used my old translation that didn't try to use arrays and everything is good now!